# rails routing not working as expected when in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, relative-path

I noticed that my navigation/routing does not work as I thought it would when I am in a different controller.

My route:

```
get 'help/version_history' => 'about_and_helps#version_history'
```

And this is how I'm linking to it:

```
<%= link_to "Version History", '/help/version_history' %>
```

If I show a specific complaint and then try to go to the menu link for the version history, I get an error.

> The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
>   You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

The url is `http://cctweb:9298/complaints/help/version_history`

If I am on the complaints index page, clicking the link takes me to the correct page with a url of `http://cctweb:9298/help/version_history`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error lies in relativity (perhaps due to the leading slash in your provided example).

To make this simpler, and to follow Rails' conventions, I recommend assigning a name to your route:

```
get 'help/version_history', to: 'about_and_helps#version_history', as: 'my_route_name'
```

Notice the `as` option. This tells the router that this route has a name, which, in my example, is set to `my_route_name`

Now you can link with the following:

```
<%= link_to "Version History", my_route_name_url %>
```

This will take care of the relativity issues and always link back to that specific route. Even if you change the route's URI down the road, everything will still work by using the route's name.

More options--and examples--can be found in the [Rails Routing Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: This is the way to go, having alias let use use them and one day, if you need to change the link, there's only one place to change it....

Comment: Thanks - That worked and now I understand it a bit better.